# How can I stop apps from flickering in 19.10?

Tags: lenovo, amd-graphics, 19.10, amd-processor

Just installed 19.10 on a [Lenovo Flex 14 81ss with Vega graphics](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/ideapad-flex-series/Lenovo-IdeaPad-FLEX-14API/p/88IP8FX1273). Apps such as "Settings" and "Tweaks" are flickering and unusable. Just the app window flickers, not the whole screen. This did not happen for me in 19.04.

Comment: Just installed 19.10 on a new HP 14-dq1033cl and the flickering is still present in gnome-tweaks but I did not yet notice it in the Settings app.

Comment: After several updates, the flickering is still present. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit of a cheap workaround, but I have a laptop with touchscreen and tweaks works correctly with the touchscreen but doesn't with the mouse. 
That may help devs to find where the problem is and was enough for me to get my extensions activated painlessly.
Hope that helps somehow :)